# Start inner loop from position of the outer

Tags: python

In my example I have two loops. One nested within the other. Is there a way I can start the inner loop from the index of the outer. Here is pseudo code.

```
arrayOfWords = ["one","two","five"]
arrayOfWords2 = ["one","two","three","four","five"]
tottalWordlist = []
for index, jString in enumerate(arrayOfWords):
    gWord = arrayOfWords[index]
    indexClone = index
    arrayOfWords2Count = range(len(arrayOfWords2)-1)
    for indexClone in arrayOfWords2Count:
        if gWord == arrayOfWords2[indexClone]:
            tottalWordlist.append(gWord)
            break
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need to add the starting index to the `range` object.

```
arrayOfWords2Count = range(indexClone, len(arrayOfWords2))
for i in arrayOfWords2Count:
    if gWord == arrayOfWords2[i]:
```

Also, you don't need to subtract one from the endpoint, as that end is exclusive.

Comment: I chose this answer because it was the first to directly answer my question. But I'd like to thank every one for the support.

Answer (score 2):

in my understanding, you are looking for whether outer list's element in inner list begin with outer element's index.

```
arrayOfWords = ["one","two","five"]
arrayOfWords2 = ["one","two","three","four","five"]


print [ item for i,item in enumerate(arrayOfWords) if item in arrayOfWords2[i:] ]

['one', 'two', 'five']
```